# def serialize(self) what does it do in django models

Tags: python, django

so i was working on a project you should know i have just started and was trying to make a login/logout of emails and some stuff and i saw this can someone help me find out what does this def serialize do here.

```
class Email(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="emails")
sender = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="emails_sent")
recipients = models.ManyToManyField("User", related_name="emails_received")
subject = models.CharField(max_length=255)
body = models.TextField(blank=True)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
archived = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def serialize(self):
    return {
        "id": self.id,
        "sender": self.sender.email,
        "recipients": [user.email for user in self.recipients.all()],
        "subject": self.subject,
        "body": self.body,
        "timestamp": self.timestamp.strftime("%b %-d %Y, %-I:%M %p"),
        "read": self.read,
        "archived": self.archived
    }
```

**i dont know what this serialize do in this class can someone help me out**

Comment: this `serialize()` is written by someone who has access to the codebase, not comes with built-in Django models. In your case, the method serializes the `Email` instance to a `dict` format

Answer (score 3):

This `serialize` method is just translating the model into other format for interoperability. In your case it's translating `Email` object into `dictionary` format.

This method is not built-in it's custom method, you can use custom method based on your use case.

Moreover, the name `serialize` is not also fixed, like `self` you can use any name as you like. `django` has also it's own `serializer` check here to know about `django serializers` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/serialization/

Answer (score 0):

It's a custom Model method developed by one of your colleagues to get a dictionary from the instance values.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#model-methods